# Turbo Sprockets and capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano, sprockets

I recently added the turbo sprockets gem https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3
to my rails application, I'm using capistrano to deploy to Amazon EC2.

I'm a little confused on how I can make this work.
assets:precompile worked on my local machine, but on the amazon instance it didn't.

Long story short capistrano makes a new release directory for each deployment and the public/assets
directory is empty, so every time it creates a new one and when running assets:precompile it precompiles all of the assets.

Should I precompile localy and add them to git or copy the public/assets directory from the last deployment before capistrano runs assets:precompile?

What would be the cleanest/best practice solution?

Or should I keep the compiled assets in a shared directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution I could think of is using the shared/assets directory to store
my assets and make a symbolic link to the the release public/assets directory before the assets are being compiled .

```
 task :assets_precompile do
   run "ln -s #{shared_path}/assets #{release_path}/public/assets"
   run "cd #{release_path} && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
 end
```

Edit: Anjan pointed out that if you use deploy:assets ( If you have `load 'deploy/assets'` in your Capfile ) this is done by default so that's a cleaner solution .

Comment: Does your `Capfile` have `load 'deploy/assets'`? I thought that line takes care of precompiling the assets on deploy and it puts it in the `shared/assets` folder by default.

Comment: It's commented out and yes deploy:assets:symlink does exactly that . I'll update my answer , thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Lesce's answer has greater weight if the deploy process includes symlinking to static files.

Example: config/database.yml  is something you don't tweak, nor want a deploy to necessarily change on you...
Having that in shared/assets will lead to failure when assets:precompile gets called.

It also works for cases with user loaded images, attachments...